# How can I point Cloud Run to my latest container image when its path changes based on version?

Tags: terraform, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-platform, gcp

I am trying to model continuous deployment infrastructure in Terraform.

The problem I have is Cloud Run requires a path to the container image, and that image's path changes based on its 'version'.

Cloud Build is triggered on git push events to a GitHub repository `main` branch, and builds and pushes the image with the following path format: `eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA`.

In Terraform, how can I configure Cloud Run's image when its path changes (and at initial infrastructure deployment) doesn't exist yet?